# background-image: url( com uma URL que tem parenteses com template Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Tenho uma div da seguinte forma:

```
<div style='background-image: url({{ OBJETO.URL }})' class="video-thumb"></div>
```

Onde `Objeto.url` entrega uma string assim:

```
http://dominio/rota/id/original/(nome)8.jpg
```

Quando ele renderiza a o HTML ele fica com valor inválido nesse background-image porque o segundo parenteses desse pedaço `(nome)` fecha o valor do url do backgroud-image.

Pelo browser, inspecionando e colocando aspas duplas em volta ele funciona.

Por isso tentei mudar o html para:

```
<div style='background-image: url("{{ OBJETO.URL }}")' class="video-thumb"></div>
```

Mas ele ignorou as aspas nesse momento.

Gostaria de saber como fazer ele considerar `(nome)` como parte da minha URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape os parênteses usando **`%28`** (**`(`**) e **`%29`** (**`)`**).